# How to read from different sections of a file using multiple threads in java and will it be efficient?

Tags: java, multithreading, nio, java-io

I would need to read a file in efficient way.

I would read the file and each word from the read file would looked into custom dictionary and decide the offset of the word in the file.

I came up with the following solution for this

**Producer thread**

Reads line by line from file   and puts each line to ConcurrentHashMap.

**Consumer threads**

Reads the line from map and looks up into dictionary for the word.

I am quite sure about implementing the consumer but not sure if using threads to read file would be helpful. Unsure about using java IO or java NIO

Updated sample code for reading from file update to map for producer

```
public class DocumentManager {


    Map<Location, String> map = null;


    public DocumentManager(Map<Location, String> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    public void readFile(String path) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(path)));

        String line = "";

        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            map.put(new Location(0, 0), line);
            //location is dummy at the moment
        }
  }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by, "efficient"?  A multi-threaded program is _always_ less efficient than a single-threaded program if "efficient" means making the best possible use of CPU cycles, but a multi-threaded program running on a multi-processor host can be more efficient than a single-threaded program if "efficient" means getting the job done in the least amount of real-time.

Comment: File I/O often is a bottleneck.  How much of a bottleneck depends on the nature of the file system.  If you're talking about a classic (i.e., rotating) hard drive, then it doesn't matter much how many CPUs are available to run your code if the drive only has one head array.  Even if it's a solid state drive, it's connected to the host through one interface, and if your program is able to process data as fast as it can be pulled through the interface, then there's no way that adding more threads will make it go any faster.  Some times, the best way to find out is by trying it.

Comment: It is basically pointless. The disk is not multithreaded. The days of fixed-multi-head disks are decades past. You can read millions of lines a second with a `BufferedReader`. If that isn't enough, nothing is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using threads is not free, and passing a object between threads via a blocking queue can be surprisingly expensive.  However updating a Map, while not free, is much cheaper than passing work between threads.

Most likely you will spend most of your time reading and parsing the file.  If you have a text file it is very hard to do this using multiple threads, and even harder to make it faster than just reading it in one thread.

Comment: Ok. Lets say one thread reads a line at a time puts into ConcurrentHashMap and consumers would read from the map. I guess this could do trick

Comment: @ChannammaVadigeri what would the consumers do that the producer can't do? You could just update the Map with the result you want.

Comment: what I thought is readLine in bufferedReader class would block until a line is read, i thought I can make use this time of CPU to process in different thread. I am quite new to java, so please excuse if any wrong statements I made. Just updating with the sample code thats in my mind

Comment: @ChannammaVadigeri if you have another thread it can run on the CPU while you have a blocking operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RandomAccessFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) in each thread to read different sections of the file. RandomAccessFile allows you to read bytes starting at the file pointer and advance the file pointer past the bytes read.

Comment: You would need to make sure you are reading a whole word at even if you start at random.  You would also need to ensure you update a local copy of the counting and only merge at the end, but it could be done.